# Neo4j - how to create two relationships at once?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a new node and link this node to two other nodes.
It is failing with the message:
QueryExecutionKernelException: A single relationship type must be specified for CREATE (line 6, column 11 (offset: 912))

```
create (d:Description{description_text:"Gegenstand der Arbeit ist die Untersuchung von Ortsumbenennungen auf dem Territorium der russischen Teilrepublik der Sowjetunion (RSFSR). Welche Entscheidungswege gab es? Nach welchen Kriterien wurden die Namen gewählt? Der Schwerpunkt der Arbeit liegt auf dem Kaliningrader Gebiet, wo über die Siedlungsnamen hinaus auch fast alle Flur- und Gewässernamen ausgetauscht worden sind. Auch die Umbenennungen auf der Krim, auf Sachalin und in Karelien werden auf ihre Motivationen hin analysiert. Zugleich wird das Thema in den Kontext der europäischen Geschichte des 20. Jahrhunderts eingebunden; Umbenennungen sind eines der Mittel zur Schaffung von Gedächtnisorten für neue politische und gesellschaftliche Verhältnisse. "})
with d
match (w:Woka{woka_id:'97836530481000000000'})
match (l:Language) where (l.iso_639_2_code = 'ger')
create (w)-[:DESCRIBED_BY]->(d)
create (d)<-[DESCRIBED_IN]-(l)
;
```

How can I change this in order to succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your query, and the exception you get is a bit confusing.

In fact you are missing a semicolon `:` for the second relationship type.

create (d)<-[`:`DESCRIBED_IN]-(l)

Then it is working